# How to download/migrate multiple files from Digital Ocean Spaces to GCP Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, google-cloud-storage, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I have plenty of spaces on Digital Ocean, where there are multiple folders with 100s & even 1000s of files. I need to migrate them all to GCP Cloud Storage, but its too almost impossible to do that manually. Is there any way, that I can directly migrate all the data from Digital Ocean Spaces to Cloud Storage? Or first download it locally then upload to Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 3):

After some RnD, I came across this tool called [rclone](https://rclone.org/) which is very simple and efficient for migrating data between different remote servers.

After installing rclone over your system or any VM, we can create profiles for different remote servers or clouds, using this command

```
rclone config
```

Once the details for source and destination servers are configured, rclone provides bunch of commands to interact with them. Similarly, there's copy command which helped me to migrate 1000s of files in less than a minute.

```
rclone copy source:/directory destination:/directory
```